# Cannot access property of JSON in VueJS using a loop index

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My VueJS running app displays activity data from Strava, grouped together by week, over a 20-week period. The difficulty that I'm having is that the object from my API appears, but I cannot access each property.

These are the relevant excerpts from the SFC.

**DATA**

`weekly_total_data` will grow as the weeks progress

```
data() {
        {
            return {
            activity_weeks: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
            weekly_total_data:
               [{"week_number":3,"total_distance":39877.6,"total_moving_time":11841},
                {"week_number":2,"total_distance":58596.4,"total_moving_time":18719},     
                {"week_number":1,"total_distance":41347.5,"total_moving_time":12796}]
            }
        }
    }
```

**FUNCTION**

Acccessing the data

```
    matchWeeklyTotals(){
        var x = this.weekly_total_data
        console.log(x)
        return x
      }
    },
```

**TEMPLATE**

Looping through the weeks, getting an index for each week, and then using that to display the appropriate data for the week

```
<div v-for="(week, week_index) in this.activity_weeks" v-bind:value="week._id">
   <div class="container max-w-xl mx-auto">
       <h2 class="text-2xl">Week {{week}}: {{ (matchWeeklyTotals()[week_index])}}</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

As it stands, I can display the object, but when I do `matchWeeklyTotals()[week_index][total_distance]`, as an example, it fails.
I have also tried variations of JSON.parse.

Any help to access the `total_distance` and `total_moving_time` appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about `v-bind:value="week._id"`. Have you tried `matchWeeklyTotals()[week_index].total_distance`?

Comment: Yeah - tried that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is working.

I'm filtering `weekly_total_data` to check if the `activity_weeks` exists in `weekly_total_data` => `week_number`

```
<script setup>
const activity_weeks = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

const weekly_total_data = [
  {"week_number":3,"total_distance":39877.6,"total_moving_time":11841},
  {"week_number":2,"total_distance":58596.4,"total_moving_time":18719},
  {"week_number":1,"total_distance":41347.5,"total_moving_time":12796}
]

const matchWeeklyTotals = () => {
  var x = weekly_total_data
  console.log(x)
  return x
}

</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="week in weekly_total_data.filter(x => x.week_number in activity_weeks)">
     <div class="container max-w-xl mx-auto">
         <h2 class="text-2xl">Week {{week.week_number}}: {{ week.total_distance }}</h2>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood You correctly, You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      activity_weeks: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
      weekly_total_data: [
        {"week_number":3,"total_distance":39877.6,"total_moving_time":11841},
        {"week_number":2,"total_distance":58596.4,"total_moving_time":18719},     
        {"week_number":1,"total_distance":41347.5,"total_moving_time":12796}
      ]
    }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="(week, week_index) in activity_weeks" v-bind:value="week._id">
    <div class="container max-w-xl mx-auto">
      <h2 class="text-2xl">Week {{ week }}:</h2>
      <p>{{ weekly_total_data[week_index]?.total_distance }}</p>
      <p>{{ weekly_total_data[week_index]?.total_moving_time }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works as expected. Thanks!
It feels too easy though - is it recommended?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access data through a getter, make sure your getter is a computed property

```
export default {
...,
computed: {
matchWeeklyTotals() {
return this.weekly_total_data;
}
}
}
```

And when you access them in the template, you don't need to call the function using parenthesis, so you can access them directly as

```
<h2>
{{ (matchWeeklyTotals[week_index])}}
</h2>
```

Also I would recommend adding a check to ensure if the item of that weekIndex exists, and if possible match the week_number number value and use a find function, or map the array in a form where you can access the data directly in case there's a sorting issue in the data at some point. You could also map the weekly_total_data array directly, unless there's a specific reason to have multiple arrays

Comment: Thanks. Good call on the checks!
I still can't access the `total_distance` property though, with matchWeeklyTotals[week_index]['total_distance'] or matchWeeklyTotals[week_index][total_distance], or period separated. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you try printing matchWeeklyTotals[week_index] and see what you get here, i usually go with printing Object.keys(matchWeeklyTotals[week_index]) and typeof matchWeeklyTotals[week_index] to make sure I'm printing what I was trying to print, first start with printing matchWeeklyTotals, then matchWeeklyTotals[0], then access property from 0 index everywhere, matchWeeklyTotals[0].key, to make sure its not an issue due to the looping of the other array, if it isn't then maybe move on to debugging if its something else

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a copy of the issue on something like codepen so others can take a look?

Comment: Hey @Wasiq . Well I've outputted it to the console, and it formats as a JSON nicely, but apparently that can be misleading. Feels like Optional chaining (?.) is the way to go. Thank though!